# Will this type of RJ45 connector affect data transmission speed?

Tags: networking

My Ethernet cable was chewed by a rat and I saw [this product](https://www.vcelink.com/products/ethernet-cable-extender-adapter-vcelink) on the Internet.
It is an **Ethernet Cable Extender Adapter VCELINK KJ21-C7-2P**.

It says that this extension connector can repair the cable without affecting the speed. Is it true? Is it worth buying this product? Or is it better to buy a new Ethernet cable? Thank you much if you can help me.

Comment: In what way is the cable broken? How easy would it be to replace the cable - is it buried in a wall or something?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have the tools, you will be spending about $32 to buy the coupler, side cutter, and stripper.  I would suggest that a new cable would be cheaper.

This is also a fiddly job.  You have to get wires in the right place, of the same length, and all stripped to the same length, without nicking the copper cores.  If not done properly, the cable may not work or may be error-prone.  Unless you have had experience with stripping and crimping tools, I would suggest getting a tech to join it up.

With regards to speed, it will not be affected if the connections are made reliably.  Any transition such as this contributes to a loss in the signal amplitude.  This means that the maximum distance for the cable is reduced.  I doubt that this would affect you in any way.

Finally the crucial bit - this will only help you if you know where the damage is.  You need to cut off the damaged bit and then couple the cable together.  **If you do not know where the damage is or if the cable is damaged in multiple places, this will not help.**

Comment: I also suspect this isn't something you'd DIY - it would be something a tech would use as an alternative to pulling new line 'if' say someone drilled through a cable, or there was an accident with a drywall saw or something along those lines.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - yes, because it is fiddly.  Will incorporate it in.

Comment: Well by fiddly we mean both "involves delicate work" and "ripping out a good chunk of the wall"

Answer (score 0):

If the cable is accessible, you can try DIYing it yourself. It's not difficult. Many tutorials on YouTube can help you out.  As for tools, you can get away with just a stripper and a kitchen knife. VCELink's connector and stripper should cost you 10 bucks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).